# How can I convert a jsonb nested string field to int in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 11 and I have a jsonb field.

```
amount
----------------------------------------
{"value": "3590", "currency": "AUD"}
```

I can use this syntax to select the nested field `value`: `select amount->'value'`.

but I don't know how I can convert it to integer and sum it, like `select sum(amount->'value') from`

I got this error: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I tried to convert it by

```
select sum(amount->'value')::DECIMAL
select sum(TO_NUMBER(amount->'value'))
```

but none of them working. What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator to get the value as `text`:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

```
SELECT SUM((amount->>'value')::INT)
```